# Introductory example on serving data from sqlite database via REST API with the yesod web frame work in haskell

Tags: sqlite, rest, haskell, ysod

I want a "keep it simple and stupid" (i.e., "make it as simple as possible but not simpler") way of serving data that is stored in a sqlite data base. In haskell I want to use the ysod web framework. Actually, as I am only severing data, I need to implement simply GET requests.

I am not interested in generating html, css, javascript, session management, user management, web blog applications, authentication, etc.

The last two hours I read several webpages from the Ysod Book and tutorials on fpcomplete. Up til now I could not get an example running.

Finally I tried to get an [example from a blog post](http://scrollingtext.org/my-first-yesod-app) running . Although the example is not too old and from 2013, yesod changed a lot since then and it is not obvious on how to get the example running.

I adapted the following lines in the [blog post example](http://scrollingtext.org/my-first-yesod-app). Missing language extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables        #-}
```

Further `persist` is no longer available, thus `persistLowerCase`:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Stuff
    value Text
    ValueName value value
    deriving Show
|]
```

Still, there are probably a bunch of fixes needed to get the example running.

So prior to investing more time my question is: *where do I find a up to date example or tutorial on how to use ysod with sqlite to program a REST API serving JSON data?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [the Yesod book's Persistent chapter](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent#persistent_integration_with_yesod)?

Comment: Just to check and be absolutely sure, is the boock chapter up to date with 1.4.0 version of yesod? Also, if I want persistance with a database file, how do I need to change the line `main = runSqlite ":memory:" $ do runMigration migrateAll`? I would assume this line stores the data base "in memory" (i.e., in computer RAM so that persistance is gone one the haskell program is terminated)?

Comment: Yes, it's up-to-date. Just change `":memory:"` to a filepath. It's a feature of SQLite itself.